# Program closes after user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a simple program that is basically just dice, I am using Thonny as my IDE and the program works fine in there but when I try and open the .py file the question comes up then I type something and the window just closes.
Any help is appreciated.

```
import random
#-------------------------
print("Made by Thr i ving")
roll = input("Type roll to roll the dice: ")

if roll == 'roll':
    nums = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
    print("Your number is: " + random.choice(nums))
else:
    print("Try again.")
```

Comment: That's likely because the program immediately ended after printing out the number, closing the console window.  Try putting another `input()` statement after everything (like `input("press enter to exit")`) and see if that achieves what you want.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the issue i was having.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you're expecting the code to ask again the user if the entered text is not exactly 'roll'.

If that's correct, I'd use a while loop to wait for the correct input.
Until the word 'roll' is entered, the program will keep asking the user for a new input:

```
import random
#------------------------- print("Made by Thr i ving")
roll = ""

while roll != 'roll':

    roll = input("Type roll to roll the dice: ")

    if roll == 'roll':
        nums = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
        print("Your number is: " + random.choice(nums))
    else:
        print("Try again.")
```